# Delete From sys.views With Wildcards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I can run a delete statement on my server, but anytime I add a `where` clause to my delete statement it throws an error of:

> Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

This syntax throws the error ->

```
DELETE 
FROM sys.views
WHERE sys.views.name LIKE '%DoNotNeed_%'
```

What am I setting up incorrectly in order to delete all views that are prefaced with Do Not Need?

Comment: Why are you deleting from `sys.views`? Have you tried `DROP VIEW ..`?

Comment: @vercelli - would syntax be Drop View Where View.Name Like....

Comment: No, `Drop view DonotNeed1;` `Drop view DonotNeed2;` ...

Comment: There is no way to drop all views in one pass?

Comment: If they are too many you can create de staments to execute with `select 'drop view ' + name + ';' FROM sys.views
WHERE sys.views.name LIKE '%DoNotNeed_%'`

Comment: perfectly!  That "DE" statement will work, thank you!

Comment: Do not delete from system tables, please...

Comment: No, these are views that will be deleted not tables.  So sys.tables will not be touched.

Comment: I didn't explain myself, sys.views is a system view, you can't delete from it (and you shouldn't). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/ms190334.aspx

Comment: As a sidenote, be aware that '_' is a wildcard itself in SQL so you might end up dropping more than you expect. You can escape it like: `select 'drop view ' + name + ';' FROM sys.views WHERE sys.views.name LIKE '%DoNotNeed$_%' escape '$'` At least this is how it is defined in the SQL standard, I don't know if sql-server does it any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative dynamic SQL approach (which also includes schema, often important!):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N',' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(v.name)
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.views AS v
ON s.[schema_id] = v.[schema_id]
WHERE v.[name] LIKE N'%DoNotNeed[_]%';

SET @sql = N'DROP VIEW ' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, N'') + N';';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

This will produce a command like the following, which is legal (you don't need a `DROP VIEW` command for every view):

```
DROP VIEW [dbo].[view1], [dbo].[view2], [dbo].[view3], ...;
```

When you believe it is correct (and [note that `PRINT` might not output the entire command if it exceeds 8k](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)), uncomment the `EXEC`.

Note that whatever solution you use, you might run into difficulties dropping certain views (for example, they could be referencing by objects that use `WITH SCHEMABINDING`). In which case you may want instead to use something a little more elaborate:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
BEGIN TRY
  DROP VIEW ' + name + N';
  PRINT N''   Dropped ' + name + N'!'';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT N''Could not drop ' + name + N'!'';
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH'
FROM 
(
  SELECT name = QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(v.name)
   FROM sys.schemas AS s
   INNER JOIN sys.views AS v
   ON s.[schema_id] = v.[schema_id]
   WHERE v.[name] LIKE N'%DoNotNeed[_]%'
) AS x;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Parts of this solution can be complicated if you have views with `'` in their names. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You are deleting from `sys.views` which is a system view and you are not allowed to do that ...

> Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

You cannot delete a view, you can drop it.

```
select 'drop view '+quotename(name) +';'  as [DROP COMMANDS] from sys.views 
where name like '%DoNotNeed_%' -- filter !
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop all views on the instance via the following PowerShell script. Edit YourInstanceName before running. This will drop all views with DoNotNeed_ in the name from all databases on the instance. This script could easily be extended to do the same against hundreds of instances by adding another level of iteration.

```
Import-Module SQLSERVER

$ViewsToDrop = @()
Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance <YourInstanceName>| % {
    foreach ($View in $_.Views) {
        if ($View.IsSystemObject -eq 0 -and $View.Name -like '*DoNotNeed_*') {
        $ViewsToDrop += $View.Name
        }
    }
    foreach ($ViewToDrop in $ViewsToDrop) {
        if($_.Views.Contains($ViewToDrop)) {
            $_.Views[$ViewToDrop].Drop()
            Write-Host "$ViewToDrop has been dropped from the $_ database"
        }
    }
    }
```